# Perl Catalyst: Resultset and Relations

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have two tables in my database and one of the tables is associated with my Accounts table.

So in my Schema Result for Account.pm I added the following line.

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many('subjects', 'MyApp::DBIC::Schema::Subject', {'foreight.account_id' => 'self.account_id'});
```

Then in my controller I make a search like this.

```
$c->stash->{search_results} = $c->model('DB::Account')->search(
{ -or => [
   firstname => {like => '%'.$search_term.'%'},
   'subjects.subject_title' => {like => '%'.$search_term.'%'},
 ]
},
{
 join => 'subjects',
 rows => '3',
},
{
 order_by => 'first name ASC',
 page => 1,
 rows => 10,
}
);
```

It does not output any errors, but I can't figure out how to output the results on my view file. Is this a correct method of making relations between two tables?

My goal: provided a `search_term`, search two tables and output the result in view file. My SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT FROM Accounts,Subjects WHERE Accounts.firstname=$search_term OR Subjects.subject_title=$search_term LEFT JOIN Subjects ON Accounts.account_id=Subject.account_id
```

And would want to output the result in view file, as I stated above.

I am fairly new to Perl and some of the documentations don't make that much sense to me, still. So any help and tips are appreciated.

Comment: *I can't figure out how to output the results on my view file.* — That's done by `$c->stash->{search_results} = ...`. How you then deal with it then depends on the View you are using.

Comment: *Is this a correct method of making relations between two tables?* — Usually you would define the relations in the database schema. Sometimes you'll still want to be explicit about the join when you call the query though.

Comment: *My SQL would look something like* — You can see what the SQL actually looks like by setting the environment variable `DBIC_TRACE=1` before running `yourapp_server.pl`

Comment: *any help and tips are appreciated* — You might like to `use` your database schema in a command line script so you can play around with (and get to grips with) DBIC without having Catalyst wrapped around it.

Comment: @Quentin Does not output the SQL, so I guess it is not executing any?

Comment: It's more likely the environment variable isn't set properly or you aren't looking for the query on the command line you want the server from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in your query:

Try:

```
$c->stash->{search_results} = $c->model('DB::Account')->search(
  { -or => [
      firstname => {like => '%'.$search_term.'%'},
      'subjects.subject_title' => {like => '%'.$search_term.'%'},
    ]
  },
  {
    join => 'subjects',
    order_by => 'firstname ASC',
    page => 1,
    rows => 10,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The join looks OK to me, but it would make sense to try a simplified version without the join to check that everything else is OK.

The behaviour of `DBIx::Class::ResultSet::search` differs depending on the context in which it's called. If it's called in list context then it executes the database query and returns an array of `MyApp::DBIC::Schema::Account` objects. For example:

```
my @accounts = $c->model('DB::Account')->search();
```

In your case you're calling `search` in scalar context, which means that rather than returning an array it will return a `DBIx::Class::ResultSet` object (or a subclass thereof), and crucially it won't actually execute a db query. For that to happen you need to call the `all` method on your resultset. So, assuming you're using the default template toolkit view you probably want something like this:

```
[% FOREACH search_result IN search_results.all %]
    [% search_result.first_name %]
[% END %]
```

This 'lazy' behaviour of DBIx::Class is actually very useful, and in my opinion somewhat undersold in the documentation. It means you can keep a resultset in a variable and keep executing different search calls on it without actually hitting the DB, it can allow much nicer code in cases where you want to conditionally build up a complex query. See the [DBIx::Class::Resultset](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08210/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#search) documentation for further details.